# Dynamically Allocate Memory to a Connecting Player then Destroy it when he leaves (Mixed Types)

Tags: c++, class, oop, networking, memory

I'm currently working on a C++ project that involves players, each player will need information stored about him on the server in order to determine what he's doing or how it should respond. The server can have up to 1000 slots, and I don't want to leave unused memory just allocated to the program and not created and destroyed when the player connects or joins.

I understand that I can allocate memory dynamically like this:

```
int *Pointer = new int Example[10];
```

This would allow me to store 10 integers which I could hold some information on that player. However what I don't know and why I'm asking this question:

How can I use this, or something with a similar function to store information on the player. Like a struct or a class made specifically to hold that players data. Then delete it once he leaves?

An example of what I would need it to hold would be a mixed range of values:

```
double Pos[3];
int Mode;
string Name;
```

In other words I need it hold a mixed type of variables, and be able to link this directly back to the player ID it relates to?

Thanks.

Comment: Make a class that manages all of a player's data, create an `std::unique_ptr` to an allocation of the object, destroy the unique_ptr when they disconnect?

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll look into it :). I've had a quick few clicks through on Google and it looks like what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help, and sorry for the dumb question. I'm still learning :).

Comment: @user1591117 - Why do you need to dynamically allocate when you know up-front at compile time the number of entries?  All you need is `int Example[10];`  If the number of Examples was known only at runtime, then the better choice would be to use `std::vector<Example>`

Comment: I need to because, there are 1000 slots for players. Although what if only 10 people are playing. I have allocated memory in that case for another 990 players, which would be a waste of memory. As far as I can see, unique_ptr will allow me to dynamically assign memory to each player, and be able to trace this pointer back to a specific player ID. If I can get my head around this, I will then be able to have my server only hold the memory for 10 players if there were only 10. Or 1000 should that number ever be met.

Comment: @user1591117: That's why we suggest `std::vector<Player>`. It will grow as necessary. It can start with 2 players and grow to a million.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `Player` class to store information for a player.

```
class Player {
public:
  double Pos[3];
  int Mode;
  string Name;
};
```

Then you can define a `map` to associate the player ID with the `Player` object.

```
map<int, Player*> playerList;
```

When connecting a player, you can allocate memory like this:

```
Player *p = new Player();
int playerID = xxx;
playerList[xxx] = p;  //store the <playerID, p> relationship in the map
```

Then you can access the fields as you want:

```
p->Pos[i] = xxx;
p->Mode = xxx;
p->Name = xxx;
```

When the player leaves, you can deallocate memory like this:

```
int playerID = xxx;
Player *p = playerList[playerID];
delete p;  //deallocate the Player class
playerList.erase(playerID); //deallocate the map entry that stores the <playerID, p> pair
```

For more advanced uses of `class`, you can refer to this [tutorial on classes](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).
You can also refer to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) to learn about how `map` can be used.

Comment: This is the right concept, though I would strongly suggest using a smart pointer if possible, rather than using raw pointers.

Comment: This is what I was trying to do initially, however I couldn't assign the value of the pointer to a player. After this I started playing with the vector include, which just confused me.

I still haven't worked out how to directly link a pointer, smart or normal to a specific player ID. As everything requires "a constant value". Which a playerid, will change during the function OnPlayerConnect.

Such as maybe a Pointer Array int *pInfo[MAX_PLAYERS]; which never worked. I've tried a lot of guess work, and googling.

Comment: @user1591117 Based on your description, I have updated my answer above. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No upvote because pointer. You don't even need a smart pointer. `map<int, Player>` works just fine. I'd even consider `std::set<Player, Player::OrderByName>` (std::set would try `Player1 < Player2` if you don't provide an explicit order)